# Show HTML content with events, loaded from the backend in Vue template

Tags: vue.js

I need to show an image and HTML content with events in the template.

The `HTML` of the template comes in part from the backend and I need to do a treatment on the front end.

I need to put an image in the new `HTML`.

I'm doing it this way, but it doesn't work.

The image is always empty.

```
<template>
    <div
      v-html="resultado"
    ></div>
</>    
data: ()=>({
    resultado:null
}),
mounted(){
    fillElement();
},
computed:{
    getImage() {
      return require("@/assets/pdf.png");
    },
},
methods:{
 fillElement(){
  //get html from backend
  const ohtml=getHtmlFrmBackEnd();
  let p1 = `<div>Image<img :src='getImage()'></img>${ohtml}</div>`;
  this.resultado = p1;
 },
}
```

Comment: v-html wont interpolate `:src`, if you really need this functionality i.e dom from api, use something like [v-runtime-template](https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template)

Comment: Why are you not placing the p1 contents directly in the template and populate `ohtml` dynamically? If you only want the local image to render when `ohtml` has been populated, just place a `v-if` on the container `<div>`.

Comment: Something aproximating [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-frog-hr2dx?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue).

Comment: I think the OP is looking for something like `https://engagepdq.com/` check the network requests to /sections endpoint, built using above v-runtime-template, images are imported with the bundle `import images from '@/assets/*.*'` and then referenced `:src="images.filename.jpg"` etc bit beyond the scope of SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="resultado"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";

export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
      resultado: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    compiledData() {
      return {
        resultado: null
      };
    }
  },
  methods: {
    delay() {
      //making a backend call
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(
            "<input type='button' name='btnVoltar' id='btnVoltar' value=' Voltar ' class='button' v-on:click='fVoltar()'>"
          );
        }, 1000);
      });
    },
    replace(content) {
      this.resultado = Vue.component("template-from-server", {
        template: content,
        methods: {
          fVoltar() {
            console.log("click");
          }
        }
      });
    },
    async fillElement() {
      //get html from backend
      const ohtml = await this.delay();
      let p1 = `<div>Image<img src='${require("@/assets/logo.png")}'></img>${ohtml}</div>`;
      this.replace(p1);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fillElement();
  }
};
</script>
```

---

**[Working Code Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-violet-qzk6z?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)**

---

You can see I loaded the image directly into the `src` and called `fillElement()` with `this` keyword in the `mounted()` hook.

I also added a `delay` function to demonstrate a request to the backend.

---

**Edit:**

In order to handle events coming with the template from the backend, I created a mini component within the current component that will get rendered once the content is passed. For that, I had to locally import `Vue`.

Please keep in mind that you will need to replace `onclick` with `@click` or `v-on:click`. You can use `regex` for that as you have done so already.

Comment: sure, but it won't if it is indeed from a remote call as the OP codes suggests

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? In the code provided by the OP, there were few issues that I believe I accounted for. Why do you think the above code does not solve the problem? Possibly I misunderstood the problem and would appreciate correcting me. Thanks.

Comment: if contents from an api includes anything dynamic like v-bind or the require call its not going to work with v-html, and will need to bundle require which wont happen on the fly, it works on your because its on the instance for bundler to see

Comment: Indeed if that is actually the case. It would be ideal to see how the content from the api looks like though. I worked based on the code from the question and just fixed visible issues. Let's see if there is more clarification so we could find a better solution.

Comment: @Jakub A Suplicki  Thank you, This is working to me. Now, another question please. I have in html coming from back end a button with an event. Such as "<input type='button' name='btnVoltar' id='btnVoltar' value='  Voltar   ' class='button' onclick='fVoltar()'>. I used regex and replaced onclick with '@click.stop' and created a method "fVoltar" in vuejs to handle the  click. But It´s never is called.

Comment: @LuizAlves That is great to hear. I edited the answer to account for events. I also added a few notes to clarify some things. I hope that we were able to find an optimal solution this way. Thanks.